# Chart not resizing/ obeying chartArea option when being redrawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization

I have a POST form that feeds new params to Chartkick. It calls `Chartkick.options` when the corresponding controller method runs, but for some reason, the `chartArea` options are not obeyed when it redraws. The chart appears 65% smaller than before.

What's weird is that all of the other options like color/ axis/ legend are obeyed. When I resize the window, the small chart then resizes to full width! I tried setting the chart width inline `<%= area_chart @chart_data, width: "100%" %>`, but it still rendered small.

Chart when page loads
[image: Chart when page loads]

Updated chart when form submitted
[image: Updated chart when form submitted]

Updated chart when window resized
[image: Chart when page resized]

Javascript that submits the form

```
var formSubmit = function() {
  $('.chart-radio-icon').change(function(){
    $('#mega_form').submit();
  });
};

$(document).ready(formSubmit);
```

Setting `Chartkick.options` in controller

```
def set_default_options(chart_type)
    default_options = {
      colors: ['#d2080e', '#c464d0'],
      library: {
        chartArea: {
          top: 45,
          right: 40,
          bottom: 40,
          left: 80
        },
        animation: {
          startup: true,
          duration: 1500,
          easing:  'out'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#2a2a2a',
        fontName: 'Calibri',
        curveType: 'function',
        vAxis: {
          gridlines:{
            color: '#333333'
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: '#a0a0a0'
          }
        },
        hAxis: {
          format: 'MMM d',
          baselineColor: '#000000',
          textStyle: {
            color: '#a0a0a0'
          }
        },
        axisTitlesPosition: 'none',
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
          alignment: 'center',
          textStyle: {
            color: '#a0a0a0',
            fontSize: 14,
            bold: true
          }
        },
        lineWidth: 3,
        pointSize: 7,
        crosshair: {
          trigger: 'both',
          opacity: 0.2
        },
        dataOpacity: 0.7,
        tooltip: {
          textStyle: {
            color: '#2a2a2a'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    case(chart_type)
    when chart_type = "initial_chart"
      Chartkick.options = default_options
    when chart_type = "mega_chart"
      Chartkick.options = default_options
    else
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: that would make a lot of sense. it doesn't know the size of it's container because it's container doesn't exist. can that be fixed in the js?

Comment: not familiar with chartkick, but re-drawing the chart after the container is visible should fix -- similar to "on resize"...